# How to wait value from a flow when using db operations?

Tags: android, kotlin, asynchronous, android-room

I use room database with the select function:

```
@Query(SELECT * FROM user_public_details WHERE userId = :userId)
fun getUserPublicDetails(userId:String): Flow<UserPublicDetails>
```

My question is in my view model, How can I wait for this operation to return the value before move to the next steps in my view model function?
I'm also using Firestore query in my view model and I can await the query in the view model scope. Why Flow isn't simple like that?

Comment: The `Flow` may emit just once or it may emit many times as the data in the affected table(s) change. If you are only looking to get one value, do not use `Flow`, but instead use `suspend fun`.

Comment: Do suspend function called in the view model scope  wait for the value to load before continue?

Comment: @LoïcJackotin yes, if it is made in a blocking fashion.